# How do I make a custom tensorflow probability layer?

Tags: tensorflow-probability

I am trying to make a tensorflow probability probabilistic model that learns the linear relation as well as the error in Linear Regression. Obviously its a toy problem and as been kind of solved in [an official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression). There the model is

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1 + 1),
  tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
      lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :1],
                           scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(t[...,1:]))),
])
```

The problem is that this learns the relation where the error is a function of the independent variable.

If I do not want that I can make the following model

```py
std_val=tf.Variable(1.)
model = Sequential([
    Dense(1,input_shape=(1,)),
    tfpl.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=t,
                                                                 scale=std_val)))
])
```

and indeed it gives the correct result but also the following warning

```py
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (distribution_lambda_22), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
```

My question is how do I go about making the subclassed Layer the message is talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do it but it would still be useful to know a more general way to make custom Distribution layers. The way I have is to subclass the DistributionLambda layer

```py
class MyClass(tfp.layers.DistributionLambda):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.std_val = tf.Variable(1.)
        super().__init__(lambda t: tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=t,scale=self.std_val)))
        
    
model = Sequential([
    Dense(1,input_shape=(1,)),
    MyClass()
])
```